# Adapt SQL Query with an Excel valua

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012

I'm using Excel 2013 to get data from a SQL Server 2012 database,
I successfully get data using an SQL Query, but now I want that query to be dynamic, based on the Month and Year.
How is it possible to use a cell value (a spreadsheet cell) as a parameter for such a query?
I use this Query:

```
    SELECT [Class_02] AS [MS Part Number]
          ,[701].[dbo].[ItemClasses].[Description] AS [Item Name]
          ,ROUND([701].[dbo].[frhsrg].[esr_aantal]/3, 0) AS [Aantal]
          ,[701].[dbo].[ItemAccounts].[SlsPkgsPerPurPkg] AS [Prijs]
          ,SUM(DISTINCT [701].[dbo].[frhsrg].[esr_aantal]) * [701].[dbo].[ItemAccounts].[SlsPkgsPerPurPkg] as Totaalprijs

FROM [701].[dbo].[Items] 

      WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, fakdat) =  '2013'
      AND DATEPART(QUARTER, fakdat) =  '1'
      AND [701].[dbo].[frhsrg].[docnumber] LIKE '%kwartaal%'
```

I have two values in **Excel** (Month and Year) like March 2013, and then the DATEPART statement in SQL has to be based on that. I use the Excel 2013 Add-In PowerPivot to fill the Excel sheet with the SQL Query output. How does the SQL Query need to be to do this?

In forward, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

... I you have the query saved as a string in your Excel VBA macro (I'm assuming that is where this query is run from), simply write it as follows:

```
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, fakdat) =  <<YEAR>>
AND DATEPART(QUARTER, fakdat) = <<MONTH>>
```

Basically having `<<YEAR>>` and `<<MONTH>>` as placeholders, then you can just use the `Replace` function looking something like this:

```
Replace strSQL, "<<YEAR>>", Range("A1").Text
```

where `strSQL` would be the SQL string

Comment: Thanks for you comment but no, i am not using a Excel VBA Marco. 
I inserted the Query into a PowerPivot Table (Excel 2013 Add-In) so i really need to adjust the SQL Query to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Customize a parameter query - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-a-parameter-query-HP010216113.aspx